# CSS or image for submit button?

Tags: css

What are the advantage and disadvantage of using both?

1. CSS

   ```
   <input type="submit" class="removeBtn" />

   .removeBtn{
       background: url(Images/Remove.png);
       height: 25px;
       width: 25px;
   }
   ```
2. Inline

   ```
   <input type="image" src="Content/Images/Remove.png" />
   ```

Comment: Could someone fix the code for me? I cant seem to get it to show up in code blocks.

Comment: @Lol coder: Done. Code blocks within lists are a pain - you need to indent twice, so 8 spaces per line :)

Comment: Also consider `<button><!-- MORE HTML!--></button>` ?

Comment: @JohnP: More specifically, `<button type="submit">`.

Comment: @BoltClock yup. For some reason or another, most people don't use that tag too much

Comment: @JohnP: I am one of the privileged few! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Semantically speaking, you should always use a submit button.  A user with a screenreader will have no idea what the function of your image input is.

Edit: as per comments, the image button will automatically submit a form as well as an input with type="submit"

Comment: `<input type="image">` functions as a submit button too. But good point about accessibility, unless the image input's `alt` attribute mentions its submit functionality.

Comment: @BoltClock is exactly right, if you use it correctly, there is no problem with `input type="image"`. If you put this info into your answer, I will be ready to upvote.